# i am always getting error code 2000

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What's with error code 2000 that I am always getting interrupted by facebook.
The application I am developing right now exchanges status likes between users who they allowed app to do that themselves. There is a users pool in my database and user links their facebook status to get likes and others users do the same thing in exchange. Only thing to avoid this situation creating new app in developers.facebook.com, but after few hours I am getting blocked by facebook again with error code 2000 "The specified feature has been temporarily disabled for this application." I am not doing any illegal thing afaik. If facebook doesn't allow me to do that, why there is a like permission in graph api?

Comment: Have you verified you have not put Country or other restrictions in your Facebook app settings?  Visit https://developers.facebook.com/apps -> Settings (Advanced) -> App Restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

If your features were restricted by Facebook you should have received an email explaining what happened and why - check you're not violating any [policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy)  of theirs with your app

Do you have a sample API call you're making which is failing? It sounds like you're expressly violating Facebook policy by auto-liking things, so i wouldn't be surprised if that's why your app is restricted

Comment: i have checked my emails there isnt anything about my app nor facebook.its failing at likes. if it gets interrupted by facebook my app stops liking. my users are complainting about this

Comment: I think your app is probably hitting spam protections because as you've explained it to me, it's against policy - if it is, this is probably what's happening to your app

Comment: yes but there are similar apps to mine but they are still working after months